# How to override ASP.NETCORE route?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes

how can i use parameter routing?
my project use .Net 6.0
like:
`https://localhost:7203/v1/users/123/items?action=delete`
and
`https://localhost:7203/v1/users/123/items?action=claim`

i want use code

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("/v1/users/{userId}/items")]
public void Delete(string userId)
{
   //TODO...
}

[HttpPost]
[Route("/v1/users/{userId}/items")]
public void Claim(string userId)
{
   //TODO...
}
```

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking but it sounds like it's a terrible idea.

Comment: agree with @DavidG and @keithwill-the-upvoter,  your `action` in a query parameter and you shouldn't try to convert it to be the action route

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPost("/v1/users/{userId}/items")]
public void PerformUserItemAction([FromRoute] string userId, [FromQuery] string action)
{
   if (action == "delete")
   {
      //...perform delete
   }
   else if (action == "claim")
   {
     //...perform claim action
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you, i know this is the norm, but i can't change request parameter, is there a way I can route this situation?

Comment: Exposing an API that takes one HTTP verb and performs another is an anti-pattern, but if you need it to solve some problem, I'll amend my answer.

Comment: yes, i can't change this URL, if you can help me, thank you so so so so much!

Comment: I updated my answer. It treats the action as a part of the request instead of the HTTP verb. Please do not ever use this approach with an endpoint that uses an actual GET verb though, it may react in unexpected ways to caching and retries from proxy servers in between your client and server. Please give me an upvote and mark me as the answer if I was helpful.

Comment: can i routing "action"? just like change ASP.NETCORE Route, because "delete" has Body like {"deleteId":101}, but "claim" body like {"claimId": 102}

Comment: No, query string is not a part of routing in ASP.NET Core. You might be able to implement a custom route constraint for each type of verb you are mimicking and it would only return a match when the action matches. See this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#custom-route-constraints

Comment: thank you so much,I would try to convince the requester to use the spec

Answer (score 0):

If you really need use `POST` to execute delete action
then your parameter name ***MUST*** the same as action's parameter
example:
if your uri is
`https://localhost:7203/v1/users/123/items?action=delete`

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("/v1/users/{userId}/items")]
public void RouteAction([FromRoute]string userId,[FromQuery] string action)
{
   // Use your action string to decide action 
   switch(action){
   case "delete":
        // do something for deleting 
   case "calim":
        // do something for claiming
   default:
        return;
   }
}
```

***BUT*** it is better to specify httpDelete to your delete action

Comment: i have many Method, just like https://localhost:7203/v1/users/123/items?action=claim, so i want to routing "action" to method. I know it's not the norm,but...

Answer (score 0):

Like HsuTingHuan said. It is probably better to use the correct HttpRequestMethods like `[HttpDelete]` for the delete action. But if you really need to do it like you said try this:

`[Route("/v1/users/{userId}/items?action=claim")]`

`[Route("/v1/users/{userId}/items?action=delete")]`

Comment: it's not working, System.ArgumentException:“The literal section 'items?action=claim' is invalid. Literal sections cannot contain the '?' character. Arg_ParamName_Name”